# Recursive function not refreshing a list inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the following class:

```
class Node:

def __init__(self, id, parent):
    self.id = id
    self.parent = parent
```

Some objects of the node class:

```
n0 = Node(0, None)
n1 = Node(1, n0)
n2 = Node(2, n1)
n3 = Node(3, n2)
```

And a recursive function to get an hierarchy tree:

```
def get_hierarchy(node, hierarchy_list=[]):
parent = node.parent
if parent:
    hierarchy_list.append(parent)
    return get_hierarchy(parent, hierarchy_list)
else:
    return ', '.join(str(node.id) for node in reversed(hierarchy_list))
```

If I call the that function outside a loop it works as expected:

```
hierarchy = get_hierarchy(n3)
print(hierarchy)
# 0, 1, 2
```

But if I call that function inside a loop, the `hierarchy_list` varible is not refreshed on each loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    nodes = [n0, n1, n2]
    hierarchy = get_hierarchy(n3)
    print(hierarchy)
    # 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
```

And if I force the `hierarchy_list` to be empty on each interaction, it works as expected:

```
for i in range(5):
    nodes = [n0, n1, n2]
    hierarchy = get_hierarchy(n3, []) # forcing to be empty
    print(hierarchy)
    # 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2
    # 0, 1, 2
```

Why python does not refreshes the `hierarchy_list` on each interaction since I am calling the `get_hierarchy` function outside `get_hierarchy`'s scope, and if I force it to be a new list it works. And what is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Do not use mutable as default argument value, because it's ... mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that you are using a mutable argument as the default value in the function, which is a bad idea. The list is initiated only once when the function is defined, not re-initiated every-time you call the function.

The default value of the function argument points to the same list everytime you call that function, so the `append` method keeps adding to the same list. When you force it to be an empty list, the argument points to a new empty list avoiding the issue you are having.

Have a look [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) for the same explanation.